# How to switch the cursor between terminal and code in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I just started using VSCode and I'm looking for a way of, while having both the code open and the terminal(the one inside VSCode), switch between typing on these parts of the editor with a shortcut.
Looked around the web but the best I could find would be to close and open the terminal.

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: At current moment there is a default of Ctrl+1(2,3,...) to focus on a pane you want, where number denotes the pane number. So, if you have opened terminal and one pane just use Ctrl+1 to focus to the pane and Ctrl+` to focus on a terminal, no need to close the terminal. Also there is a good shortcut of Ctrl+Q which gives roulette like view of other windows(explorer, source, control, terminal, etc., except panes with code)

Answer (score 110):

I found bit hard to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>. It also close the terminal when we press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>'</kbd>

So, I configured mine as following:

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+j",
  "command": "workbench.action.focusActiveEditorGroup",
  "when": "!terminalFocus"
},
{
  "key": "ctrl+k",
  "command": "workbench.action.terminal.focus",
  "when": "terminalFocus"
}
```

> **Step to configure:**

1. Go to: File > Preferences > keyboard shortcuts
2. Then in the search-bar, search for `focus terminal`
3. Select `workbench.action.terminal.focus` and then <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> or press your custom key and then press enter.
4. Similarly, in the search-bar search for `focus active  editor group`
5. Select  `workbench.action.focusActiveEditorGroup` and then press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> or press your custom key and then press enter.

> **After the above setup:**

- Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> to ***focus cursor*** on **terminal**
- Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> to ***focus cursor*** on **coding section** without closing terminal

Comment: Great answer, I opted for the Intellij/IDEA settings of ctrl + tab + ctrl + t.  Thanks for making this easy to follow +1.

Comment: the "when" condition should be reversed. It should be "when": "!terminalFocus" for Ctrl-K

Comment: I prefer to flip the keybinds so `ctrl+j` goes *down* to the terminal which is similar to my vim keybinds for switching windows, which is similar to vim's natural movement keybinds. `ctrl+k` goes *up* to the code for the same reasons. I also left off the `when` condition since it's not really needed in my case.

Comment: Doesn't this kill the two-part keybindings that rely on first pressing `ctrl+k`?

Comment: you can replace `!terminalFocus` with `editorTextFocus`

Comment: Is it possible to use the same key to jump between terminal and editor? :)

Comment: @kev, yes, this is possible. Just make sure to use the correct `when` conditions. (Or actually it even seems to work without, as in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1514504/24380)).

Comment: Actually, it seems to be possible to use the same key to jump between the terminal and the editor, given the "when" conditions. (I had to edit the `Code/User/keybindings.json` file to add those lines.)

Comment: @AspiringDev Yes. Ironically, binding to `ctrl+k` conflicts with the shortcut that opens the Keyboard Shortcut UI itself, which is `ctrl+k, ctrl+s`.

Comment: I couldn't find where to put this input but the steps show up here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42796887/switch-focus-between-editor-and-integrated-terminal

Answer (score 34):

Refer to this Question/Answers [Switch focus between editor and integrated terminal in Visual Studio Code on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42796887/switch-focus-between-editor-and-integrated-terminal-in-visual-studio-code), I think @Trav L answer might be closed one. But need to config a little bit more.

#### VS Code v1.26.1 as a base version

1. Open keyboard shortcut editor from menu File->Preferences->Keyboard Shortcuts (`Ctrl+K Ctrl+S`)
2. Click on the link `keybindings.json` above the screen.
3. Overwrite your custom keyboard shortcuts on the right side panel, the `keybindings.json` file will store in your `<user dir>\AppData\Roaming\Code\User`. With this values you can overloading the `key shortcut` with using `when` keyword like code below.

> **Credit**: @wgj user of Stackoverflow
>
> ```
> // Toggle between terminal and editor focus
> { "key": "ctrl+`", "command": "workbench.action.terminal.focus"},
> { "key": "ctrl+`", "command": "workbench.action.focusActiveEditorGroup", "when": "terminalFocus"}
> ```

4. Now you can toggle cursor position by press the same key `` Ctrl+` ``, VS Code will recognize base by situation where the cursor is.

#### Special 1

Use `Settings Sync` extension for saving your custom key binding and others to your secret GIST (Github), for switching between workstation, it's recommended from me. It's quite convenient for me.

#### Special 2

Some time I need to kill the terminal pane for get the whole code area screen. So I also setting this to `keybindings.json`. The result is equal to clicking on the X mark of the terminal pane. (Just change to your favorite key if you would like to)

> {
>           "key": "ctrl+k ctrl+`",
>           "command": "workbench.action.terminal.kill"
>       },

Comment: I would advice against workbench.action.terminal.kill since it kills the terminal instead of hiding it, so the next time you show it, you have to wait (it's quick I know) until it loads.

Answer (score 16):

Generally VS Code uses `ctrl+j` to open Terminal so I created a keybinding to switch with `ctrl+k` combination, like below at `keybindings.json`:

```
[{
    "key": "ctrl+k",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.focus"
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+k",
    "command": "workbench.action.focusActiveEditorGroup",
    "when": "terminalFocus"
}]
```

Answer (score 7):

You do this by setting the keybindings for `Focus Terminal` and `Focus Active Editor Group`. These two will allow you to switch the focus between the Editor and the Terminal, without having to just close the terminal.

The other positive is if you perform some action that causes another panel to open such as Output or Problems. Using the keystroke for the editor group will change your focus back to the editor.

I can't say what these are by default because I set this long ago in Code. As you can see from the screenshot below I set them to the same keybinding: <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd>.

This makes them act as a toggle switch so it takes the focus back and forth. You can basically just hold down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd>, then hitting <kbd>i</kbd> will move your focus back and forth.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

What I like to do is

- Focus on **terminal**

  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>
- Focus back to **Editor**

  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Answer (score 4):

Here is how to have the same hotkey to switch back and forth from code to terminal for maximum productivity:

```
    {
        "key": "f1",
        "command": "workbench.action.focusActiveEditorGroup",
        "when": "terminalFocus"
    },
    {
        "key": "f1",
        "command": "workbench.action.terminal.focusNext",
        "when": "!terminalFocus"
    },
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> to toggle between terminal and the text editor, then do the following:

1. Open your `keybinding.json` file: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> then select `Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)`.
2. Add the following line:

```
  { "key": "ctrl+`", "command": "workbench.action.terminal.toggleTerminal" },
```

3. Save and close `keybinding.json` file.

Comment: best answer. easy and simple.

Comment: This is good, although it closes (hides?) the terminal when toggling away.

Answer (score 2):

To switch between the editor and terminal in VS Code (Mac), you can use the following keyboard shortcuts:

`Ctrl` + `~`: To go to the terminal

`Ctrl` + `1`: To go back to the editor

`Ctrl` + `up`: To select the editor when the terminal is focused

`Ctrl`+`Shift`+`P`: to open the command palette and search for Focus

Comment: ...and `command`+`b` to toggle the left side panel containing Explorer, Extensions, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Toggle Integrated Terminal

> Ctrl + `

This will turns on/off terminal viewport while switches your cursor back and forth between editor and terminal.

Comment: OP specifically stated: "the best I could find would be to close and open the terminal."

Answer (score 0):

I see you already got some options, but I wanted to add the method I use.

```
Press CTRL + SHIFT + p
Write 'view terminal'
Command palette should now show: View: Toggle Integrated Terminal
Press ENTER
```

Now you can use CTRL + SHIFT + p followed by ENTER to toggle between terminal and the text editor as long as that command is the last used in the command palette.

***This option will hide the terminal when you go back to the editor.***

An alternative that only shifts focus and keeps terminal visible is here:

```
View: Focus First Editor Group
Terminal: Focus Terminal
```

Also found in the command palette.

I know they are not direct shortcuts, but I find the command palette easy to work with, since I have the commands I often use a few clicks away by using the down arrow.

Comment: What is Ctrl+Shift+P supposed to do? Does nothing for me with default keybindings.

Comment: Command Palette#

VS Code is equally accessible from the keyboard. The most important key combination to know is Ctrl+Shift+P, which brings up the Command Palette. From here, you have access to all of the functionality of VS Code, including keyboard shortcuts for the most common operations.

Comment: Oh, I wasn‘t in VSCode but in Visual Studio Professional which is something different. Nvm

Answer (score 0):

There is no default shortcut for switching between terminal and editor in VScode. But you can add **USER shortcut** in the ***Settings > Keyboard Shortcuts***.

**Note:-**
I have placed **"Altr + Ctrl + ,"** for Editor Focus and **"Altr + Ctrl + ."** for Terminal Focus as shortcuts, as they are not used by any other tasks and are easy to reach.

> In Keyboard Shortcuts, type ***Focus Active Editor Group*** and DOUBLE CLICK
>   the option and create your own shortcut and press ENTER.
>
> In Keyboard Shortcuts, type ***Terminal: focus terminal action*** and
>   find the option exactly we have written above i.e. "***Terminal: focus
>   terminal action***" and create your own shortcut and press ENTER

There are many similar options related to terminal focus like previous terminal, next terminal etc but they already have shortcuts, so it would be easy to find it.

Well, i have provided the method for windows, And i am not sure about IOS and LINUX, But I think it will work.

Answer (score 0):

answer rolling for April 2021

to focus to your differents panel of VSCode you have to edit your "workbench" commands :

1. <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> +<kbd>CTRL</kbd> +<kbd>S</kbd> otherwise <kbd>Files</kbd> > <kbd>Preferences</kbd> > <kbd>Keyboard Shortcut</kbd>

   look for this command

   `workbench.action.terminal.focus`

   and then add your prefered keybinding  for this command
   [image: vscode zoom on commands]
2. to focus to your code you have to set the following command

   `workbench.action.focusActiveEditorGroup`
3. to focus into the file explorer of vscode you have to set the following command

   `workbench.files.focusFilesExplorer`

and no more need to search to the mouse or to quit your keyboard for the touchpad

That's all folks ! Hope you will spend less energy on your touchpad ... !

Answer (score 0):

In case that somebody wants to switch between the editor window above and the panel below, regardless of whether the Terminal, the Debug Console, the Output window or the Problem window is opened right now, you can use this code:

```
{ 
    "key": "ctrl+.", 
    "command": "workbench.action.focusPanel"
},
{ 
    "key": "ctrl+.", 
    "command": "workbench.action.focusActiveEditorGroup", 
    "when": "panelFocus"
}
```

It took me a bit of trying out until I found that strangely it is `focusPanel` in the command, but `panelFocus` in the when-condition.

Note that in my example, I am using "ctrl+.", not "ctrl.+`".

Answer (score 0):

Very convenient way to switch between editor and terminal with maximize the window by the default shortcut Ctrl+`

```
  {
    // disable default rule
    "key": "ctrl+`",
    "command": "-workbench.action.terminal.toggleTerminal",
  },
  {
    // If active, maximize the terminal. If maximized, toggle and focus to the editor.
    "key": "ctrl+`",
    "command": "runCommands",
    "args": {
      "commands": [
        "workbench.action.toggleMaximizedPanel",
        //"workbench.action.focusActiveEditorGroup",
      ]
    },
    "when": "terminalIsOpen && terminalFocus && !toggleMaximizedPanel"
  },
  {
    // Open the terminal
    "key": "ctrl+`",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.toggleTerminal",
    "when": "!terminalIsOpen"
  },
  {
    // Hide the terminal, if editor is active
    "key": "ctrl+`",
    "command": "workbench.action.togglePanel",
    "when": "terminalIsOpen && !terminalFocus"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

In version 1.86.2 on linux (i dont know whether it is matter) The default keybinding for toggle between the editor, the terminal, and the side bar is `F6` and `Shift+F6` for reverse toggle.

In more details in the keybinding.json file:

```
{
  "key": "f6",
  "command": "workbench.action.focusNextPart"
}

{
  "key": "shift+f6",
  "command": "workbench.action.focusPreviousPart"
}
```

Comment: Which file is this?